# What is the difference between \declare@shorthand and \defineshorthand in babel?

Tags: babel, shorthands

What is the difference between `\declare@shorthand` and `\defineshorthand` in `babel` (v.3.9)? Which of the two macros is preferable in a language definition file?

`babel.pdf` manual (v.3.9) provides an example

```
\defineshorthand{"*}{\babelhyphen{soft}}
\defineshorthand{"-}{\babelhyphen{hard}}
```

and russian.ldf provides similar defintions using `\declare@shorthand`, e.g.

```
\declare@shorthand{russian}{""}{\hskip\z@skip}
\declare@shorthand{russian}{"~}{\textormath{\leavevmode\hbox{-}}{-}}
```

Answer (score 13):

from `babel.sty`:

```
\def\defineshorthand{\declare@shorthand{user}}
```

defines shorthands for the namespace `user`

```
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"a}{\textormath{\"{a}\allowhyphens}{\ddot a}}
\declare@shorthand{russian}{""}{\hskip\z@skip}
```

is used *internally* for the specific language setting. In the above example one for `ngerman` and the other for `russian`.

So `\defineshorthand{"*}{\babelhyphen{soft}}` is the same as

```
\declare@shorthand{user}{"*}{\babelhyphen{soft}}
```

If you want to define your own language setting which will be loaded by `babel` then use the internal definition. If you have only a few new shorthands then use the user definition.

Answer (score 5):

In 3.9

```
\declare@shorthand{russian}{""}{\hskip\z@skip}
```

is (will be) just an optimized version of

```
\declareshorthand[russian]{""}{\hskip\z@skip}
```

This shorthand is defined for `russian` and is active only when this language has been selected. Without the optional argument, it's a user shorthand, which is always active and takes precedence over language shorthands. In language definition files, the preferred command is the optimized one (ie, `\declare@shorthand`).

Comment: Can I substitute `\declare@shorthand{russian}{""}{\hskip\z@skip}` with `\declare@shorthand{russian}{""}{\babelhyphen{empty}}` in `LDF`? It might be less effective but will be more clear.

Comment: Javier, I have couple of questions/proposals on development of babel-alpha. How I could contact you?

Comment: Igor, you can either use the LaTeX list (public) or send to me a message using the form in http://www.tex-tipografia.com/contact.html (and then to continue by e-mail). I'm finishing the first beta release. (And instead of `\babelhyphen` you can use the internal `\bbl@hy@empty`.)